# Reading csv and adding to List<Custom class> gives inconsistent null values

Tags: c#, list, csv, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read a csv file with 5 columns (int, str, int, str, str):

```
1234, wef23, 1, Mary, Smith
1234, wef23, 1, Mary, Smith
```

and add them into a list:

```
private List<PermittedUsers> okUsers = new List<PermittedUsers>();
```

PermittedUsers is defined:

```
 class PermittedUsers : MonoBehaviour{
                public int IdNum, part;
                public string upi, firstName, lastName;
                public PermittedUsers(int id, string up, int pt, string fname, string lname){
                    IdNum   = id;
                    upi     = up;
                    pt      = part;
                    fname   = firstName;
                    lname   = lastName;
                }
```

However, after the import, both firstName and lastName are null, and part is a default 0 value. However, both upi (as a string) and IdNum (as an int) add to the list as expected. The importing code is:

```
// import 5 column csv: ID, UPI, yearLevel, First, Last
var dataset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("permittedUsers"); // this is loading the file in Unity without System.IO
var dataLines = dataset.text.Split('\n');
for(int i = 1; i < dataLines.Length-1; i++) { // skip header line and last empty line
    var data = dataLines[i].Split(',');
    okUsers.Add(new PermittedUsers(int.Parse(data[0]), data[1], int.Parse(data[2]), data[3], data[4].Replace("\r", string.Empty)));
}
```

Debugging and examing the data i can see it returns a string[5] with correct values (as strings).

I am most confused by the *inconsistency* here, why would upi, but not fname add to the List correctly? Why IdNum, but not pt? It happens with **all** rows in the CSV, so I don't believe it's due to special characters. What else am I missing?

Comment: Looks like a typo .. the assignments of the strings in your consteuctor should be the other way round .. ;) Either way... **using `new` on `MonoBehaviour` is forbidden!** Are you sure it even should be a `MonoBeuaviour` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be leaving certain properties of the `PermittedUsers` unpopulated when you call the constructor.

> ```cs
>    class PermittedUsers : MonoBehaviour{
>    public int IdNum, part;
>    public string upi, firstName, lastName;
>    
>    public PermittedUsers(int id, string up, int pt, string fname, string lname){
>        IdNum   = id;
>        upi     = up;
>        pt      = part; // possible flipped assignment
>        fname   = firstName; // possible flipped assignment
>        lname   = lastName; // possible flipped assignment
>    }
> ```

Most notably

> `pt = part;`

looks like it should be `part = pt;`

and

> `fname   = firstName;`
> `lname   = lastName;`

should be

```cs
firstName = fname;
lastName = lname;
```

A quick tip to avoid this, if this was the issue, is to always use the `this` keyword in the constructor. This helps you as the developer see that the properties(fields in your case) are being properly set on the object instead of the other way around. For example:

```cs
class PermittedUsers : MonoBehaviour{
   public int IdNum, part;
   public string upi, firstName, lastName;
   
   public PermittedUsers(int id, string up, int pt, string fname, string lname){
       this.IdNum   = id;
       this.upi     = up;
       this.part = pt;
       this.firstName = lname;
       this.lastName = lname;
   }
}
```

Comment: In general it shouldn't be a `MonoBehaviour` either! It is not allowed to implement a constructor nor use `new` for `MonoBehaviour`!